# Drop multiple tables in Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

I just want to drop all table that start with "T%".

The db is Netezza.

Does anyone know the sql to do this?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the catalog views and `execute immediate` it is fairly simple to write this in nzplsql. Be careful though, `call drop_like('%')` will destroy a database pretty fast.

```
create or replace procedure drop_like(varchar(128))
    returns boolean
    language nzplsql
as
begin_proc
declare
    obj record;
    expr alias for $1;
begin
    for obj in select * from (
        select 'TABLE' kind, tablename name  from _v_table where tablename like upper(expr)
        union all
        select 'VIEW' kind, viewname name from _v_view where viewname like upper(expr)
        union all
        select 'SYNONYM' kind, synonym_name name from _v_synonym where synonym_name like upper(expr)
        union all
        select 'PROCEDURE' kind, proceduresignature name from _v_procedure where "PROCEDURE" like upper(expr)
    ) x
    loop
        execute immediate 'DROP '||obj.kind||' '||obj.name;
    end loop;
end;
end_proc;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a script and then execute it. something like this...

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

SELECT @SQL = STUFF((SELECT   CHAR(10)+ 'DROP TABLE ' + quotename(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + quotename(TABLE_NAME)
               + CHAR(10) + 'GO '
               FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE Table_Name LIKE 'T%'
               FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
PRINT @SQL
```

**Result**

```
DROP TABLE [dbo].[tTest2]
GO 
DROP TABLE [dbo].[TEMPDOCS]
GO 
DROP TABLE [dbo].[team]
GO 
DROP TABLE [dbo].[tbInflowMaster]
GO 
DROP TABLE [dbo].[TABLE_Name1]
GO 
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Test_Table1]
GO 
DROP TABLE [dbo].[tbl]
GO 
DROP TABLE [dbo].[T]
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find tables with a certain name in Netezza using this query.

```
select *
from _v_table a
where lower(tablename) like 't%'
```

@M.Ali is correct that you need to wrap the results in a script if you want to automate dropping the tables.   Below is a VBScript that would execute the task.

```
SQL = "select tablename from _v_table a where lower(table_name) like 't%'"

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open "NETEZZA_DSN" 

Set rs = conn.execute(SQL)   

    Do while not rs.eof 
        tblnm = rs.fields("tablename")
        DROP_TABLE_SQL = "drop table " &  tblnm
        wscript.echo "Dropping table: " & tblnm
        conn.execute  DROP_TABLE_SQL

    rs.movenext()
    Loop
conn.close
wscript.echo "Process Complete"
```

Answer (score -1):

Run the below SQL:

`SELECT 'DROP TABLE '||TABLENAME||';' FROM _V_TABLE WHERE TABLENAME LIKE 'T%'`

> Please ensure that correct database is selected before executing the
>   above query.

The above query will return output like :

```
DROP TABLE TABLENAME1;
DROP TABLE TABLENAME2;
.
.
DROP TABLE TABLENAMEn;
```

Now, just copy the above SQL result to SQL editor and drop all the tables in a single run.

Comment: Hey, this is for netezza and working perfectly. Read whole answer first before marking incorrect.